# 1993 Mercedes 300e should there be movement in my power streering pulley?

Tags: noise, mercedes-benz, power-steering

Been hearing a sound coming from the car. I thought maybe water pump as I had changed it once before. What happens is when I start car it begins to smoke up front and I hear a scheeking sound. I tried to locate the tensioner pulley, but just pulled the power steering pulley off because it seems to be rocking back and forth with a clicking sound??? So do I Change the whole power steering pump? And how? A video would be great if anyone has one.